# Can't run the choice command in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm having a huge problem with this. I've written a simple batch script that lets you make a choice, and that's all. The problem is it doesn't work. None of my batch scripts that has the choice command, even the ones I KNOW worked before today, has stopped. I'm really not sure whats wrong, but I need to know if it's me or something else. The first script doesn't work, but for whatever reason the second works find.

```
@echo off
:START
cls
Title Main Menu
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO {Hello}
echo.
ECHO 1. Hi
ECHO 2. Hello
set /p choice=Please select choice: 
if '%choice%'=='1' echo Hi
if '%choice%'=='2' echo Hello
if not '%choice%'=='' ECHO "%choice%" is not valid please try again
cls
pause

:START
cls
Title Main Menu
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO {Hellow}
echo.
ECHO 1. Hello
ECHO 2. Hi
set /p choice=Please select choice: 
if '%choice%'=='1' cls goto Hello1
if '%choice%'=='2' cls goto Hello2
if not '%choice%'=='' ECHO "%choice%" is not valid please try again
cls
```

When I open the batch file in cmd it normally closes to fast for me to read. However I was finally able  too read it a word at a time, and it says "<1 is not a valid choice". It might be an easy fix, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
:LOOP
CLS
ECHO(
ECHO(
ECHO {Hello}
ECHO(
ECHO 1. Hi
ECHO 2. Hello
SET "MyChoice="
set /p "MyChoice=Please select choice: "
if "%MyChoice%"=="1" (
    ECHO Hi
) ELSE (
    if "%MyChoice%"=="2" (
        ECHO Hello
    ) ELSE (
        if not "%MyChoice%"=="" (
            ECHO "%MyChoice%" is not valid please try again
            PAUSE
            GOTO :LOOP
        )
    )
)
```

you should not use `cmd` keywords for batch variables or jump labels (`start`, `choice`)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, however the script says that same thing as mine "<1 is not valid". I'm just curious, do you see anything wrong with my script? Something I forgot to add or spelled wrong? I know for a fact it was working the other day. Again thanks for the response.

Comment: @user2728767 my script works here without any error message :|

Comment: @user2728767 you should use always double quotes for escaping, not single one. Remove all occurences of `choice` from your script, replace it with `MyChoise` and look at the error message. If you do this, the message can't longer contain `choice` ...

Comment: I can use the script exactly as is right? I mean that I don't need to change anything. When I copy the script into my test.bat it closes saying "<1 is not valid". Exactly like my script. Other than the choice part...

Comment: When the batch loads, and it gives me the choice of 1. or 2. I've tried typing both 1, and 2 separately into it. Without the periods of course. It then says "<1 is not valid".

Comment: I have no explanation for this :/, please check if you have `SET "MyChoice="` before `set /p ...`

Comment: I'm going to update my question with a little more info. Please see if this helps any.

Comment: `if '%choice%'=='1' cls goto Hello1` is not valid, try `if "%choice%"=="1" cls &goto Hello1`

Comment: lol... The second script works perfectly fine for me. No errors at all. However when I remove the cls or add it to my original script it stops working and gives me the error "<1 is not a valid choice". Thanks for the help, but i'm pretty much going to call it quits with batch for now. If you can find any reason why this is happening please post it, and I'll give it a try.

Comment: `if not '%choice%'==''` is `true`, if you enter `1`. If you add `cls`, you can't see this message `:-)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I know that cls clears the screen. The reason I used it was so when you get to the Hello1,and Hello2 the screen wouldn't have the Hello or Hi. I didn't post the Hello1, and Hello2 only because it stops before I can get to them.

Comment: The problem to me is finding out what constitutes "working". Without knowing what you EXPECT to happen for any particular input, we're guessing. Your claim that "second works find" doesn't correspond with your posted code. Without the `&`, the `GOTO` is ineffective. Moving the `PAUSE` before the `CLS` would show the response. There's no apparent way that `<` could appear in the response unless you're trying to redirect input - which you don't show in your post. Even with the naming/quoting problems that Endoro has indicated, your script "works" for me according to MY understanding of batch.